# Python mongoengine - retrieve _id after saving

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I need a help in storing and retrieving to mongodb from python using mongoengine. 
I am relatievely new to mongoengine and i am trying to insert a document using something like below:

Sample code i used for saving:

```
session = Session()
session =  session.from_json(sessionjson)
session.save()
```

It is saving well and good, but is it possible to retrieve _id from the saved document?
The above save is returning QuerySetManager object but it is not identifying a field called _id.
Please advice on this

Comment: Take your question out of code tags and add tags and indentation to your code please.

Answer (score 6):

After saving, you only need to check the field "id" of your document (that's is the mongoengine attribute that represents the internal mongodb "_id").

Try:

```
session.save()
document_id = session.id
```

Before `session.save()`, if your document was not already in your database, the field id will be `None`.